# Xamarin Android MetaData for a Java .aar file

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

I have to use a Java based .aar file for a project.

I know nothing about it other than the method I can call.

I simply received the .aar file but no MetaData for Visual Studio Xamarin support and I am getting few errors when I try to generate the binding.

Specifically I get several of the following type errors:

> ...obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Native.Control.Data.Position.cs

```
CS0738  'Position.CREATOR' does not implement 
interface member 'IParcelableCreator.CreateFromParcel(Parcel?)'. 
'Position.CREATOR.CreateFromParcel(Parcel)' cannot implement 
'IParcelableCreator.CreateFromParcel(Parcel?)' because it does not have the   matching 
return type of 'Object'.
```

I've tried several versions of the  statement based on research but the fit is not exact and they have failed.

Does anyone have an idea of what the MetaData should be to mitigate this error in the binding process in VS 2019 Xamarin for Android?

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

According to [C# compiling error message: CS0738](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0738), this error occurred because

> The return value of an implementing method in a class must match the
> return value of the interface member that it implements.

And there's troubleshooting guidance for this kind of error in [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings#problem-class-does-not-implement-interface-method)

Please check your binding output and make the suggested changes.